# Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-Salotime/Pods-Salotime-frameworks-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist'

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cordova, cordova-plugins

my Xcode Version:12.2

my pod version: 1.10.0

my cordova version: 10.0.0

node.js version:12.16.3

i using cordova and i just try to install firebesex plugin:https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebasex
This plugin depends on various components such as the Firebase SDK which are pulled in at build-time by Cocoapods on iOS.

my podfile:

[image]

when i try to build the project , i got the following error: "'/Target Support Files/Pods-Salotime/Pods-Salotime-frameworks-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist'"

[image]

Although the file is in right path , it's doesn't success to load contents of file

**the content of "Pods-Salotime-frameworks-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist":**

```
${PODS_ROOT}/Target Support Files/Pods-Salotime/Pods-Salotime-frameworks.sh
${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.framework
${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.framework
${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/FirebaseInstallations/FirebaseInstallations.framework
${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport.framework
${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities.framework
${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/PromisesObjC/FBLPromises.framework
${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/nanopb/nanopb.framework
```

**the content of Pods-Salotime-frameworks-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist**

```
${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/FirebaseCore.framework
${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.framework
${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/FirebaseInstallations.framework
${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/GoogleDataTransport.framework
${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/GoogleUtilities.framework
${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/FBLPromises.framework
${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/nanopb.framework
```

i already tried to use
1-pod deintegrate
2-pod update

but still it's didn't work .

Comment: Removing these input and output parameters in the POD build phases and after that 'pod install' fixed it for me.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10670

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75284225/4606368 Also not forget opening Xcode using Rosetta mode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71827725/run-xcode-project-in-rosetta-mode-from-terminal King regards.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

1. delete the platforms and plugins folder
2. remove the cached data `rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/Cocoapods`
3. Remove Derived Data `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
4. run `pod deintegrate`
5. run `pod setup`
6. run `pod install`
7. re run whatever build command you have to recreate your platforms and plugins folder

I think this error comes about because of an issue with pods not using semantic versioning. You can read more about this at https://gist.github.com/mbinna/4202236. Clearing derivedData prevent xcode from re-reading the old code

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is adding path in Input File List by mistake.

Make sure to add path in **Input Files**, not in ***Input File List***

[image]

Comment: That was my case. I simply misclicked when added that path strings. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this issue with....

1. Go to your **Targets** in xcode
2. Go to **Build Phases**
3. Next go to **Run Script** and check it has any files in input file lists or output file lists
4. Now, Remove files **(input-files.xcfilelist / output-files.xcfilelist)** using symbol **-** from Input file Lists and Output file Lists respectively