# Run xcode project in rosetta mode from terminal?

Tags: xcode, terminal, command-line-tool, rosetta

I have M1 machine,
I have one project that I only need Rosetta to run it, instead of toggle it on/off from Xcode get info menu [image]

I tried to run the command:
`arch -x86_64 open ~<PROJECTNAME>.xcodeproj`

but the project failed to build each time.

Can someone help me with a command to build the project from command line in Rosetta mode,

Comment: What does "failed to build" mean? Your `open` command would open the project, not build it. Do you want to _build_ the project or _open_ it? Or do you want to _run_ it?

Comment: I want to open the project :)

Comment: the project has to be run in Rosetta mode, but I need it only for one project, so I was looking for a way to open only one project under Rosetta mode :)

Comment: Keep two copies of Xcode and keep one of them in Rosetta mode? I'll give that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep two copies of Xcode and keep one of them in Rosetta mode. You might even name it Xcode-Rosetta so you know which is which.

That way there's no need to turn Rosetta on and off for the same app.

Comment: Perfect, great answer as usual from the great matt!
These days it is totally normal for iOS engineer to have more than Xcode version on his/her machine 

Comment: But I wish now that I had never posted this, as running in Rosetta Xcode is wrong and no longer supported.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of maintaining two copies Xcode, you can use the following command to run your default Xcode installation under rosetta:

```bash
arch -x86_64 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
```

### XCode update

With XCode 14.3 you can choose the destination architecture to be shown, you can select "Show both" to show both M1 and rosetta version of the simulator destination from the default XCode installation:

[image: Destination arch selection menu]
[image: Destination selection menu]

Comment: That's very helpful but it is an answer to a different question. :) Running in Xcode under Rosetta and running a "Rosetta destination _Simulator_" are two different things.

Comment: @matt I agree running Xcode under Rosetta is different than running a project under Rosetta, OP asked in the original question `Run Xcode project in rosetta mode` not `Run xcode in rosetta mode` or `Open xcode project in rosetta mode` :)